# Password using c-array

Tags: c++

I am creating to create a login system using c++ but I encounter some small problems on setting the password function.

1. Masking

I want to mask the password, the code is like the following:

```
#include <conio.h>

for(int j=0;j<5;j++) {
 pass2[j]=getch();
 cout<<"*";
}
```

It makes users have to input fixed length of password. So, is there a better way to mask password by using string without the limitation?

2. string vs char

The reason I prefer to use string type is that it is easier to compare (I guess). 
Since the password is required to input twice. And I can simply check them by

```
password==password_2;
```

instead of checking it one by one. (and I may not know the size_of_password.)

```
for (int i; i < size_of_password; i++){
 if (password[i]==password_2[i]){...}
}
```

Is there a way that I can easily validate the user's input? 
Thank you.

Comment: Instead of reading a fixed number of characters, read until the user presses the enter key.

Comment: you mean using char array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks similar to what you are trying to accomplish: 
[password masking in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298610/password-masking-in-c)

Basically, just check for when there is an enter character passed, and then break. Otherwise, keep `push_back`ing the string container.

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank You. But I still have some questions. 
I see it is using "const char BACKSPACE = 8;//ASCII code for BACKSPACE Key". Does it cause any trouble on other PC using unicode.

Comment: It shouldn't as 8 is the [unicode standard for backspace](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf)